# Google distance matrix, aguardar callback para continuar loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Pesquisei bastante sobre o assunto e ainda sim não consegui encontrar uma solução.

Quando executo o código abaixo, o loop prossegue antes do callback da API.

No callback a variável this.userRoute.newRoute[i].address é alterada, por isso preciso que o loop aguarde o callback, para prosseguir a partir do novo valor que foi inserido no array, que antes do callback não existe e retorna "undefined".

Minha dúvida é se eu consigo fazer com que o loop aguarde o callback ser executado para continuar a execução.

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.userRoute.route.length; i++){      
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [this.userRoute.newRoute[i].address],
      destinations: composeDestination,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    }, this.calcRouteDistanceResult.bind(this)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade descobri que não preciso fazer isso dentro de um loop.

A própria API permite que você forneça diversas origens, e retorna a distância de cada origem para cada um dos destinos, ai é só tratar o json.

Ex.:
Origem A =>
    Destino A => 2km
    Destino B => 4km
Origem B =>
    Destino A => 2km
    Destino B => 4km